# Inserting data with MySQLi - Should I use prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm making a function that takes a table name and a key value array and inserts it into my database. I'm wondering if I should use MySQLi prepared statements for this. I'm thinking that sometimes I'll have to insert similar data a bunch of times in a row. For example:

```
$db->insert('user_meta', array( 'meta_key' => 'title', 'meta_value' => 'Developer' ) );
$db->insert('user_meta', array( 'meta_key' => 'location', 'meta_value' => 'New York' ) );
$db->insert('user_meta', array( 'meta_key' => 'employer', 'meta_value' => 'Subway' ) );
$db->insert('user_meta', array( 'meta_key' => 'language', 'meta_value' => 'English' ) );
```

If my insert function used prepared statements, would this type of operation go faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the purpose of prepared statements.

Comment: it is also used to prevent sql injection even though I'm not sure how to cope with dynamic table names in such statement, I think they'll need special verification

Comment: It is bound parameters that save you from SQL injection. They just tend to be introduced at the same time as prepared statements (and provide a further performance boost when running queries that are similar rather than identical).

Answer (score 1):

You should **almost always** use prepared statements, for pretty much every specific need.

Answer (score 1):

Prepared statements is slower so i don't think that you want to use in a batch process.

http://webdevrefinery.com/forums/topic/10380-database-extension-mysql-mysqli-pdo-benchmarks/

preparing every time is evil.  So be careful.